# How to change .net framework v2.0 to v4.0 for ISAPI and CGI restrictions feature in IIS7 using command line?

Tags: iis, command-line, iis-7

I have tried to change .net framework version using below command line with .net framework v4.0 path. but it works only for restriction enable/disable but not changed .net framework version.

**C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:isapiCgiRestriction /[path='c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll'].allowed:True**

Please see below snapshots
[image]

[image]

Please provide me any good solutions.

Thanks

Comment: What's your version of Windows? I don't see the menu item in Windows Server 2012 R2 when I right-click on 'ISAPI and CGI Restrictions'.

Comment: Windows 7 x64 professional

Comment: Checked Windows 7 Pro/Ultimate - can confirm the menu items are same as yours. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as .NET Framework version **for specific IIS module**, Isapi and CGI Restrictions in your case. The menu item refers to *global* .NET Framework version setting in IIS (same you see in the right-side action panel on the first screenshot). In fact, the setting controls what version of the framework to assign to an application pool when you create one. You can use the following command:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /applicationPoolDefaults.managedRuntimeVersion:"v4.0" /commit:apphost
```

When you execute it all new application pools will have .NET Framework 4.0 assigned. However, on my box the setting in the dialog from second screenshot remains 2.0 (looks like UI/usability bug to me). See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/410757/what-does-the-net-framework-version-setting-in-iis-actually-do) for more details.